# Initialize SSD1305 OLED with STM32f3discovery

Tags: embedded, stm32ldiscovery

I'm trying to run a OLED [WEX012864GL](http://www.winstar.com.tw/products_detail_ov.php?lang=en&ProID=346) based on [SSD1305](http://www.usmicroproducts.com/sites/default/files/ic-specs/SSD1305_2.0.pdf) OLED controller with a stm32f3discovery board. I've conntected the board with a 31 pin row with first pin binding on the 3V and the last on the PD9 (this is the top-left pin row of the board). The code is looking like that:

```
#include "stm32f30x.h"

/*--------- PORT-A ----------------------------*/
#define D1      GPIO_Pin_1
#define D1_PORT GPIOA
#define D2      GPIO_Pin_3
#define D2_PORT GPIOA
#define D4      GPIO_Pin_5
#define D4_PORT GPIOA
#define D5      GPIO_Pin_7
#define D5_PORT GPIOA

/*-------- PORT-B ----------------------------*/
#define D7      GPIO_Pin_1
#define D7_PORT GPIOB
#define RD      GPIO_Pin_11 //8080 Mode RD  Display-Pin:14  PD3
#define RD_PORT GPIOB
#define DISP GPIO_Pin_15
#define DISP_PORT GPIOB

/*-------- PORT-C ----------------------------*/
#define D0    GPIO_Pin_3
#define D0_PORT GPIOC
#define D6      GPIO_Pin_5
#define D6_PORT GPIOC

/*-------- PORT-E ----------------------------*/
#define CS      GPIO_Pin_7  //PORT-D    Display-Pin:19          PD6
#define CS_PORT GPIOE
#define RES     GPIO_Pin_11 //PORT-B    Display-Pin:20                  PC10
#define RES_PORT GPIOE
#define WR      GPIO_Pin_13 //8080 Mode WR      Display-Pin:15  PD2
#define WR_PORT GPIOE
#define D_C     GPIO_Pin_15 //PORT-C    Display-Pin:18          PC12
#define D_C_PORT GPIOE

/*-------- PORT-F ----------------------------*/
#define D3      GPIO_Pin_4
#define D3_PORT GPIOF



#define GPIO_PINS_PORTA_OUT (D1 | D2 | D4 | D5 )
#define GPIO_PINS_PORTB_OUT (D7 | RD| DISP)
#define GPIO_PINS_PORTC_OUT (D0 | D6  )
#define GPIO_PINS_PORTE_OUT (CS| D_C | RES | WR)
#define GPIO_PINS_PORTF_OUT (D3)

#define GPIO_PINS_PORTA_IN (D1 | D2 | D4 | D5 )
#define GPIO_PINS_PORTB_IN  (D7)
#define GPIO_PINS_PORTC_IN  (D0 | D6 )
#define GPIO_PINS_PORTF_IN  (D3)

#define GET_BIT(cmd,bitps) (BitAction)((((uint8_t)cmd&((uint8_t)1)<<bitps))>>bitps)
#define GET_INPUT_BIT(port,pin,pos) ((uint8_t)(GPIO_ReadOutputDataBit(port,pin)<<pos))

#define MOD_GPIO_WRITE(cmd) GPIO_WriteBit(D0_PORT,D0,GET_BIT(cmd,0)); \
                GPIO_WriteBit(D1_PORT,D1,GET_BIT(cmd,1)); \
                GPIO_WriteBit(D2_PORT,D2,GET_BIT(cmd,2)); \
                GPIO_WriteBit(D3_PORT,D3,GET_BIT(cmd,3)); \
                GPIO_WriteBit(D4_PORT,D4,GET_BIT(cmd,4)); \
                GPIO_WriteBit(D5_PORT,D5,GET_BIT(cmd,5)); \
                GPIO_WriteBit(D6_PORT,D6,GET_BIT(cmd,6)); \
                GPIO_WriteBit(D7_PORT,D7,GET_BIT(cmd,7))  \

#define MOD_GPIO_READ() GET_INPUT_BIT(D0_PORT,D0,0)| GET_INPUT_BIT(D1_PORT,D1,1) | GET_INPUT_BIT(D2_PORT,D2,2)| \
                                    GET_INPUT_BIT(D3_PORT,D3,3) | GET_INPUT_BIT(D4_PORT,D4,4) | GET_INPUT_BIT(D5_PORT,D5,5) | \
                                    GET_INPUT_BIT(D6_PORT,D6,6) | GET_INPUT_BIT(D7_PORT,D7,7)

//proto
void Delay(uint32_t nTime);
void TimingDelay_Decrement(void);


static __IO uint32_t TimingDelay;
//Init the used Ports
static void Init_Ports_Write( void ) {
    //D7-0 outputs
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode    = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin     = GPIO_PINS_PORTA_OUT;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;   
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin     = GPIO_PINS_PORTB_OUT;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin     = GPIO_PINS_PORTC_OUT;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin     = GPIO_PINS_PORTE_OUT;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin     = GPIO_PINS_PORTF_OUT;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOF, &GPIO_InitStructure);

}

static void Init_Ports_Read( void ) {
    //D7-0 inputs
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode    = GPIO_Mode_IN;

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin     = GPIO_PINS_PORTA_IN;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;   
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin     = GPIO_PINS_PORTB_IN;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin     = GPIO_PINS_PORTC_IN;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin     = GPIO_PINS_PORTF_IN;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOF, &GPIO_InitStructure);

}

static void Init_Ports( void ) {

    //init the System
    SystemInit();   
    //Takt für IO-Port A & C aktivieren 
    RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOA | RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOB | RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOC | RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOD | RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOE | RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOF, ENABLE);

    if (SysTick_Config(SystemCoreClock / 1000000)) { /* Setup SysTick Timer for 1 µsec interrupts (msec/1000000) */
    while (1);                                  /* Capture error */
  } 

  Init_Ports_Write();

    GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOA, GPIO_PINS_PORTA_OUT);
    GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOB, GPIO_PINS_PORTB_OUT);
    GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOC, GPIO_PINS_PORTC_OUT);
    GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOE, GPIO_PINS_PORTE_OUT);
    GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOF, GPIO_PINS_PORTF_OUT);
    //set all neg pins

    GPIO_SetBits(RES_PORT, RES);
    GPIO_SetBits(CS_PORT, CS);
    GPIO_SetBits(WR_PORT, WR);
    GPIO_SetBits(RD_PORT, RD);

  Delay(500000);
}

static void oled_Command_25664(uint8_t cmd){
    //write bit by bit
    MOD_GPIO_WRITE(cmd);
    GPIO_SetBits(RD_PORT, RD);
    GPIO_ResetBits(D_C_PORT, D_C);
    GPIO_ResetBits(CS_PORT, CS);
    GPIO_ResetBits(WR_PORT, WR);
    __nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();
  GPIO_SetBits(WR_PORT, WR);
    __nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();
    GPIO_SetBits(CS_PORT, CS);
    __nop();

}
static void oled_Data_25664(uint8_t data){
    MOD_GPIO_WRITE(data);
    GPIO_SetBits(RD_PORT, RD);
    GPIO_SetBits(D_C_PORT, D_C);
    GPIO_ResetBits(CS_PORT, CS);
    GPIO_ResetBits(WR_PORT, WR);
    __nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();
    GPIO_SetBits(WR_PORT, WR);
    __nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();
    GPIO_SetBits(CS_PORT, CS);
    __nop();

}

static uint8_t oled_Read_Data_25664(){
    uint8_t read_data;
    //Set the D7-0 as inputs
    Init_Ports_Read();
    //set WR high
    read_data = MOD_GPIO_READ();
    GPIO_SetBits(WR_PORT, WR);
    GPIO_SetBits(D_C_PORT, D_C);
    GPIO_ResetBits(CS_PORT, CS);
    GPIO_ResetBits(RD_PORT, RD);
    __nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();
    GPIO_SetBits(RD_PORT, RD);
    GPIO_ResetBits(RD_PORT, RD);
    __nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();
    read_data = MOD_GPIO_READ();
    //Set the D7-0 as outputs
    GPIO_SetBits(RD_PORT, RD);
    __nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();
    GPIO_ResetBits(RD_PORT, RD);
    __nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();
    //read
    read_data = MOD_GPIO_READ();
    GPIO_SetBits(D_C_PORT, D_C);
    GPIO_SetBits(CS_PORT, CS);
    Init_Ports_Write();

    return read_data;
}

void Delay(uint32_t nTime)
{ 
  TimingDelay = nTime;
  while(TimingDelay != 0);
}
/* Decrements the TimingDelay variable.*/
void TimingDelay_Decrement(void)
{
  if (TimingDelay != 0x00) TimingDelay--;
}
void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
  TimingDelay_Decrement();
}
/**
  * @brief  Main program.
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
int main(void)
{
  /*!< At this stage the microcontroller clock setting is already configured, 
       this is done through SystemInit() function which is called from startup
       file (startup_stm32f30x.s) before to branch to application main.
       To reconfigure the default setting of SystemInit() function, refer to
       system_stm32f30x.c file
     */     
    Init_Ports();
    oled_Command_25664(0xAF);//--turn on oled panel
    oled_Command_25664(0xA5);
    oled_Read_Data_25664();

  while(1)
  {
    oled_Command_25664(0xA5);
    Delay(500000);
    oled_Command_25664(0xA4);
    Delay(500000);

  }
}
```

When I run the code on the board, a very bizarre result is observed - the display is not working, till I press the reset button and the there the screen light up for short and then back down. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: tl;dr: [mcve]. what is the question?

Comment: Thanks! The question is there now.

Comment: What about the **MCVE**?? Focus on the `M`

Comment: What's that MCVE stands for?

Comment: Did you even **read** my first comment?? After >1 year, you really should know. Take the [tour].

Comment: I've read you comment and the tour of course, but I want to be sure what you mean. The code is MCVE, of course you need the hardware and STM standard library to run it...

Comment: @Olaf btw did you press the down button, please press now the up. I put a lot of efforts to make this question, it was not easy.

Comment: Ok. Now it's really MCVE. Please vote up!

Comment: I've had exactly the same issue with an OLED driver circuit, after using startup code provided by the manufacturer, as a wall of magic hex numbers. Very similar to your case: the display would lit up but not work properly. For me, the problem was incorrect startup code provided by the manufacturer, simple as that.

Comment: 1) this is certainly not _minimal_! and 2) First step would be to remove the DV. The question as such is imo not worth an UV.

Comment: Well great, now you removed the most relevant part of the question :) Namely that hex number sequence.

Comment: You did not even prove your hardware connections are working. Try reading back a value written to the controller would be the first step. Walk before you run. Use a debugger to step through the code. Connect a Scope (optimal: an MSO).

Comment: Of course I have done that!!! Look, this is not a hardware problem. I have done my homework and have tested the connections they are working. You should have experience with this display to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that the DISP signal should be left high-Z or the port is not initialized. The complete code is looking like that:

```
#include "stm32f30x.h"

/*--------- PORT-A ----------------------------*/
#define D1      GPIO_Pin_1
#define D1_PORT GPIOA
#define D2      GPIO_Pin_3
#define D2_PORT GPIOA
#define D4      GPIO_Pin_5
#define D4_PORT GPIOA
#define D5      GPIO_Pin_7
#define D5_PORT GPIOA

/*-------- PORT-B ----------------------------*/
#define D7      GPIO_Pin_1
#define D7_PORT GPIOB
#define RD      GPIO_Pin_11 //8080 Mode RD  Display-Pin:14  PD3
#define RD_PORT GPIOB
#define DISP GPIO_Pin_15
#define DISP_PORT GPIOB

/*-------- PORT-C ----------------------------*/
#define D0    GPIO_Pin_3
#define D0_PORT GPIOC
#define D6      GPIO_Pin_5
#define D6_PORT GPIOC

/*-------- PORT-E ----------------------------*/
#define CS      GPIO_Pin_7  //PORT-D    Display-Pin:19          PD6
#define CS_PORT GPIOE
#define RES     GPIO_Pin_11 //PORT-B    Display-Pin:20                  PC10
#define RES_PORT GPIOE
#define WR      GPIO_Pin_13 //8080 Mode WR      Display-Pin:15  PD2
#define WR_PORT GPIOE
#define D_C     GPIO_Pin_15 //PORT-C    Display-Pin:18          PC12
#define D_C_PORT GPIOE

/*-------- PORT-F ----------------------------*/
#define D3      GPIO_Pin_4
#define D3_PORT GPIOF



#define GPIO_PINS_PORTA_OUT (D1 | D2 | D4 | D5 )
#define GPIO_PINS_PORTB_OUT (D7 | RD )
#define GPIO_PINS_PORTC_OUT (D0 | D6  )
#define GPIO_PINS_PORTE_OUT (CS| D_C | RES | WR)
#define GPIO_PINS_PORTF_OUT (D3)

#define GPIO_PINS_PORTA_IN (D1 | D2 | D4 | D5 )
#define GPIO_PINS_PORTB_IN  (D7)
#define GPIO_PINS_PORTC_IN  (D0 | D6 )
#define GPIO_PINS_PORTF_IN  (D3)

#define GET_BIT(cmd,bitps) (BitAction)((((uint8_t)cmd&((uint8_t)1)<<bitps))>>bitps)
#define GET_INPUT_BIT(port,pin,pos) ((uint8_t)(GPIO_ReadOutputDataBit(port,pin)<<pos))

#define MOD_GPIO_WRITE(cmd) GPIO_WriteBit(D0_PORT,D0,GET_BIT(cmd,0)); \
                GPIO_WriteBit(D1_PORT,D1,GET_BIT(cmd,1)); \
                GPIO_WriteBit(D2_PORT,D2,GET_BIT(cmd,2)); \
                GPIO_WriteBit(D3_PORT,D3,GET_BIT(cmd,3)); \
                GPIO_WriteBit(D4_PORT,D4,GET_BIT(cmd,4)); \
                GPIO_WriteBit(D5_PORT,D5,GET_BIT(cmd,5)); \
                GPIO_WriteBit(D6_PORT,D6,GET_BIT(cmd,6)); \
                GPIO_WriteBit(D7_PORT,D7,GET_BIT(cmd,7))  \

#define MOD_GPIO_READ() GET_INPUT_BIT(D0_PORT,D0,0)| GET_INPUT_BIT(D1_PORT,D1,1) | GET_INPUT_BIT(D2_PORT,D2,2)| \
                                    GET_INPUT_BIT(D3_PORT,D3,3) | GET_INPUT_BIT(D4_PORT,D4,4) | GET_INPUT_BIT(D5_PORT,D5,5) | \
                                    GET_INPUT_BIT(D6_PORT,D6,6) | GET_INPUT_BIT(D7_PORT,D7,7)

//proto
void Delay(uint32_t nTime);
void TimingDelay_Decrement(void);


static __IO uint32_t TimingDelay;
//Init the used Ports
static void Init_Ports_Write( void ) {
    //D7-0 outputs
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode    = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin     = GPIO_PINS_PORTA_OUT;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;   
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin     = GPIO_PINS_PORTB_OUT;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin     = GPIO_PINS_PORTC_OUT;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin     = GPIO_PINS_PORTE_OUT;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin     = GPIO_PINS_PORTF_OUT;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOF, &GPIO_InitStructure);

}

static void Init_Ports_Read( void ) {
    //D7-0 inputs
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode    = GPIO_Mode_IN;

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin     = GPIO_PINS_PORTA_IN;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;   
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin     = GPIO_PINS_PORTB_IN;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin     = GPIO_PINS_PORTC_IN;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin     = GPIO_PINS_PORTF_IN;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOF, &GPIO_InitStructure);

}

static void Init_Ports( void ) {

    //init the System
    SystemInit();   
    //Takt für IO-Port A & C aktivieren 
    RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOA | RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOB | RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOC | RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOD | RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOE | RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOF, ENABLE);

    if (SysTick_Config(SystemCoreClock / 1000000)) { /* Setup SysTick Timer for 1 µsec interrupts (msec/1000000) */
    while (1);                                  /* Capture error */
  } 

  Init_Ports_Write();

    GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOA, GPIO_PINS_PORTA_OUT);
    GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOB, GPIO_PINS_PORTB_OUT);
    GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOC, GPIO_PINS_PORTC_OUT);
    GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOE, GPIO_PINS_PORTE_OUT);
    GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOF, GPIO_PINS_PORTF_OUT);
    //set all neg pins

    GPIO_SetBits(RES_PORT, RES);
    GPIO_SetBits(CS_PORT, CS);
    GPIO_SetBits(WR_PORT, WR);
    GPIO_SetBits(RD_PORT, RD);

  Delay(500000);
}

static void oled_Command_25664(uint8_t cmd){
    //write bit by bit
    MOD_GPIO_WRITE(cmd);
    GPIO_SetBits(RD_PORT, RD);
    GPIO_ResetBits(D_C_PORT, D_C);
    GPIO_ResetBits(CS_PORT, CS);
    GPIO_ResetBits(WR_PORT, WR);
    __nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();
  GPIO_SetBits(WR_PORT, WR);
    __nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();
    GPIO_SetBits(CS_PORT, CS);
    __nop();

}
static void oled_Data_25664(uint8_t data){
    MOD_GPIO_WRITE(data);
    GPIO_SetBits(RD_PORT, RD);
    GPIO_SetBits(D_C_PORT, D_C);
    GPIO_ResetBits(CS_PORT, CS);
    GPIO_ResetBits(WR_PORT, WR);
    __nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();
    GPIO_SetBits(WR_PORT, WR);
    __nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();
    GPIO_SetBits(CS_PORT, CS);
    __nop();

}

static uint8_t oled_Read_Data_25664(){
    uint8_t read_data;
    //Set the D7-0 as inputs
    Init_Ports_Read();
    //set WR high
    read_data = MOD_GPIO_READ();
    GPIO_SetBits(WR_PORT, WR);
    GPIO_SetBits(D_C_PORT, D_C);
    GPIO_ResetBits(CS_PORT, CS);
    GPIO_ResetBits(RD_PORT, RD);
    __nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();
    GPIO_SetBits(RD_PORT, RD);
    GPIO_ResetBits(RD_PORT, RD);
    __nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();
    read_data = MOD_GPIO_READ();
    //Set the D7-0 as outputs
    GPIO_SetBits(RD_PORT, RD);
    __nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();
    GPIO_ResetBits(RD_PORT, RD);
    __nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();__nop();
    //read
    read_data = MOD_GPIO_READ();
    GPIO_SetBits(D_C_PORT, D_C);
    GPIO_SetBits(CS_PORT, CS);
    Init_Ports_Write();

    return read_data;
}

void Delay(uint32_t nTime)
{ 
  TimingDelay = nTime;
  while(TimingDelay != 0);
}
/* Decrements the TimingDelay variable.*/
void TimingDelay_Decrement(void)
{
  if (TimingDelay != 0x00) TimingDelay--;
}
void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
  TimingDelay_Decrement();
}
/**
  * @brief  Main program.
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
int main(void)
{
  /*!< At this stage the microcontroller clock setting is already configured, 
       this is done through SystemInit() function which is called from startup
       file (startup_stm32f30x.s) before to branch to application main.
       To reconfigure the default setting of SystemInit() function, refer to
       system_stm32f30x.c file
     */     
  Init_Ports();
    oled_Command_25664(0xAF);//--turn on oled panel
    oled_Command_25664(0xA4);
    oled_Read_Data_25664();

  while(1)
  {
    oled_Command_25664(0xA5);
         Delay(500000);
        oled_Command_25664(0xA4);
         Delay(500000);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Olaf have you ever worked with this display or controller?

Comment: The problem was that in the datasheet nothing was written about the signal DISP and my initial guess was to ground it.

Comment: Yet this was no reason to respond with three `!` after I claimed you should verify the hardware first. If it comes to such, you should check thrice before asserting it is working. No, I do not know the controller, but I know very similar controllers, but all need slightly different connections and settings.

Comment: Olaf I'm checking the hardware always several times before posting something to stackoverflow. This is very basic thing. Sorry about using the three!!! - didn't mean to offend anyone. But please try to understand that people may be irritated if you are assuming and saying you have not done something, so do it though they have already done it several times.